# Is there a more compact way to append to a list using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, syntax, append

I am wondering whether there is a more compact way to append to a list while in a loop. For example, the following code:

```
total = 0

for integer in range(1, 101):
    total += integer
```

may be compacted into:

```
total = sum(integer for integer in range(1, 101))
```

So, my question is whether there is an analogous way to compact the following code:

```
alist = []

for integer in range(1, 101):
    alist.append(integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a list without any loops if this is exactly what you need: `alist = list(range(1, 101))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what list comprehensions are.

```
alist = [integer for integer in range(1, 101)]
```

(Although in this specific case of course Sami's answer is better.)

Comment: What makes Sami's answer better? When would a list comprehension be the better choice?